# How to create a single variable describing these peaks?

Tags: shape-analysis

First, I would like to point out that I am a complete outsider to the field of signal processing, so please bear with me and go easy on the jargon :) I nevertheless decided to post here, because I believe your field has developed the best methods for the kind of problem I have.

I want to do a statistical analysis on a dataset. I have a list of subjects, and a measurement was taken for each subject multiple times over a time period. To do my analysis, I want to first transform my data from longitudinal, time-series data to one single number per subject that somehow describes the "peak" in the data, if there was such a peak. I would like your advice on algorithms that can be used to calculate such a number.

[image: Example data]

I am including some example data in a picture. In my layperson terminology, I would say that:

- example A has a single peak around day 23, but it is not very "large"
- example B has no real peaks, it is mostly a flat line with a bit of randomness
- example C has one "large" peak on day 33 and one "smaller" peak on day 50-51

I would like the algorithm to be able to produce a number that maps the "largeness" of the peak to a rational number and goes towards 0 when there is not really a peak. I don't have a perfect definition of my "largeness" measurement, but it should combine

1. The *steepness* of the peak start. If this were an ideal mathematical function and not a noisy measurement, I would have taken the function slope
2. The *absolute height* of the peak (the first peak in example C is higher than the peak in A because it reaches 20)
3. The *relative height* of the peak. It has to be relative to the "typical" height of the measurement for that example (I'm afraid in my picture all the data has roughly the same "typical" height between 0 and 5, but in reality, I have examples where it differs between subjects) - I am not yet sure if I want to relate it to an average over all measurements or to an average over the measurements which are not part of a recognized peak, the second is probably more informative but the first easier to calculate
4. The *duration* of the peak - the first peak in C is a very short one, but the second one has a kind of a plateau.

If there is more than one peak per subject, I am fine with taking the highest peak. A stretch goal would be to be able to recognize multiple peaks per subject, but I would have trouble defining a threshold for "real peak" and "noise". Another interesting extension would be to be able to repeat the inverse of this and recognize the largest dip per subject, defined by the same criteria as above but going under the typical height instead of upwards.

I suppose these four criteria won't be doable in a single calculation - that's OK, I can imagine taking a weighted sum of them and being able to play with adjusting my own weights. But if you know of a better way, I am open to it.

To make the task a bit harder (well, it's real-world data), the measurements are not taken at regular intervals, the intervals vary even within a single subject, and the duration of measurement varies considerably between subjects. Also, I expect that there are no underlying patterns in the noise, cyclic or otherwise. On the bright side, I am not doing any real-time calculations and I expect no more than 500 subjects, so I can afford computationally intensive algorithms.

I don't expect a full mathematical explanation of the workings of the algorithm(s) here within an answer. But as I don't have an overview over the field, I would be very grateful for sketching the kind of approach I can take, with names of algorithms and ideally pointers to books or publications that describe these algorithms. Also, if there are other important factors which determine something interesting about a peak, I am interested to hear about them.

Comment: Do the "peaks" occur at random?    In any case a pointer/link to the real data would go a long way to prompting people (probably not me) to implement an algorithm.  But...  it looks to me that you need more resolution for real analysis; i.e. the intervals between points on your graph are to crude.
Having said that some form of Wavelet Analysis might be usefull.  It's interesting and effective but does require some "on-ramp" time.  I could explain a little more but there "isn't enough room in the margin" :) :)   Try searching, on this board  as well, for that.

Comment: Is this similar to what you want? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4667093/
what sort of processing power to you have?  ML might be appropriate.

Comment: You could look at
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter
and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_filter
And there are other things depending upon what you call "noise".

Comment: @rrogers yes, you can assume that the peaks occur at random. And it is impossible to obtain more resolution. If it means that there is uncertainty in what we call a "peak", so be it.

Comment: Well for myself I would run a median filter and look at what got tossed.  You should post a link to some original data streams; the more the better, although anything above 1000 data points will do.  Then some analysis can be done by somebody else.  I found this paper that seems pretty thorough in coverage and has sections "12.3 Median Filters " (look at the tossed/residues) and "12.4.1 Impulsive Noise Detection " in: http://dsp-book.narod.ru/305.pdf
There are also statistical tests that can be done to see if the spikes are exceptional or just part of a noise pattern/distribution.

Comment: Because of so many comments making different assumptions, I will clarify a few things about the background. The data consists of measurements of blood values in patients with a rare disease, obtained from clinical documentation. There are no 1000 patients available, there are no 1000 measurements per patient available, and giving the real data to somebody else is impossible for all kinds of ethical, political and legal reasons. We found a library which might be extracting interesting parameters, but we can't tell if it assumes some kind of frequency in the signal.

Comment: Looking at it, I would say that "frequency" is the wrong term, it looks one-time/impulsive; for instance, if somebody attractive walked by.  One can't know without more info. One last engineering discipline is Outlier Detection: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.04236  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier